# Create Custom Android ROM

Tags: android, tablet, kiosk

We are going to create Kiosk type Android tablet app. Client asked us that Tablet contains only our app, we should not let the user to navigate to other apps in tablet.  We know that we need to have root access for achieve this task. We tried to create custom Android ROM. We googled for it and could not found the procedures to create custom Android ROM with our App bundled.

Note:
Our target OS version is 4.0+. We are not going to publish the app in Google store. We just distribute this app to specific peoples.

Any help much appreciated. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: This might come handy


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068084/kiosk-mode-in-android kiosk-mode in android

Answer (score 5):

Creating an entire ROM for just an application doesn’t seem to be a feasible solution. But here is the tutorial for [making a custom ROM in android](http://marakana.com/s/post/1144/android_internals_-_building_a_custom_rom_tutorials). Also when you place your app to make as system app then don’t place any of the other apps like Gmail, contacts, etc. and most important don’t place the launcher app, and you application must receive the intent for the Home button or launcher because the launcher is the application that is opened when android boots up And remember you app must be able to receive the intent for the home button also `<category android:name="android.intent.category.HOME" />`  you can check these links [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15977036/home-launcher-calling-another-launcher) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537522/how-to-reset-default-launcher-home-screen-replacement)

Also you can check these links from [XDA Forums](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2195858), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6232620/getting-started-with-creating-custom-roms) and [theunlocker](http://theunlockr.com/2010/03/26/how-to-create-your-own-custom-rom-for-android-part-1-setting-up-the-kitchen/)

**EDIT**

Ya the link of marakana seems to be broken but you can refer there video tutorials from [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1_H4AlQaNa0) and [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rFqELLB1Kk8)

Comment: making a custom ROM in android link is broken