# set custom launcher as default launcher by code

Tags: android

I am able to reset the default launcher by code with the help of following link
[How to reset default launcher/home screen replacement?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15537522/how-to-reset-default-launcher-home-screen-replacement)

Now, I want to set my custom launcher as default launcher. But the following code is not working. It crashes

ComponentName componentName = new ComponentName("com.xxx.launcher", "com.xxx.launcher.LauncheActivity");

```
            PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
            int flag = ((pm.getComponentEnabledSetting(componentName) == PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED) ? PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_DISABLED
                    : PackageManager.COMPONENT_ENABLED_STATE_ENABLED);
            pm.setComponentEnabledSetting(componentName, flag, PackageManager.DONT_KILL_APP); //crash at this line..
```

Comment: What exception do you get?  Please post the logcat stack trace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to set my custom launcher as default launcher

That is not possible. The *user* can set your home screen as the default home screen, such as by pressing HOME and choosing your app as the default. However, *you* cannot force the user to accept your home screen as the default.

> But the following code is not working. It crashes

That code does not set your "custom launcher as default launcher". That simply controls whether or not you are even a potential option for being a home screen (if you are disabled, you cannot possibly be the home screen).

As to why it is crashing, without a stack trace, that will be difficult to determine.